# Abantecart error installation error, database error(10000) in php

Tags: php

Following error has occurred during installation:
OK:

```
Name    Info
10000::database error

Error: Could not load database file DB_DRIVER! in /home/lcdmasters/public_html/tvpartsontario1/core/lib/db.php on line 49
```

Answer (score 0):

Check first what driver you have in  /system/config.php

```
// Database Configuration
define('DB_DRIVER', 'amysqli');
```

When you know driver see if driver file not corrupted and have read permissions in /core/database/ drivers folder